# Deportation symbol

Tags: visas

Does uk stamp deportation ? If so how does it look like ?! If I had applied for voluntary return after my asylum refusal will they share that to Ireland ? Or when applying for Ireland of my past immigration history which shows that I had travelled to uk and applied asylum & returned voluntarily ... Will that have a impact on my visa application to Ireland now ? Obviously I have a new passport now and I don't hold the old one in which I have my uk visa stamps ... And it's damaged !! What could the Ireland embassy see with regard to my immigration history 
1. Just the stamp that I arrived in India ? Or 
2. Will they be able to see that I have applied for asylum and on refusal I came back ?

Comment: If you had overstayed after your asylum application was refused, that will still be on record.

Comment: What you mean I overstayed ?! As I had applied for asylum I had been reporting regularly and I was informed that its refused and I was taken to detention and then I reapplied which again got refused and then I applied to return back to India voluntarily . Is any of these considered overstay after asylum?  Please let me know ..as my request to go back voluntarily was accepted and I don't think I was deported . But had a little code in he middle of my old passport page . If I am applying for Ireland student visa what chances are there for acceptance ?

Comment: Sorry, but you have a dodgy past. Repeatedly applications for asylum only makes the chances for getting a UK visa a bit more difficult. Overstaying in terms of after an asylum refusal disappearing or stop reporting your whereabouts. `If I am applying for Ireland student visa what chances are there for acceptance` Don't count on sailing through but you will need to prove emphatically to the visa officer that you are a genuine student and not one who will go underground once in the country. And considering there are no checks between Ireland and UK, it may be construed as a way to enter UK.

Comment: So you mean to say my repeated appeals would make my application tough " if I am applying for uk back again .. Wouldn't it " Or is it for Irish visa aswell ?!

Comment: NO I HAVENT DONE THAT AS YOU SAY " DISAPPEARING AT ANY CIRCUMSTANCES  or FAILED TO REPORT REGULARLY NO HAVENT DONE THAT if thatis what overstayingafter asylummeant !! No Ihave not overstayed. Ihave abidedby the law.at all times.It's just that very badadvice giver to me Iapply asylum sothat Iwill be able to see my child on his birth that's purely the intention . IFit wassomethingelse why should I report regularlyand apply toreturnvoluntarily on the firstplace.You knowwhat imean.If my intentionwas tostay Icouldhavewent undergroundthe moment Iapplied forasylum or even before that you what I mean.

Comment: don't have any intention of being back to uk becoz I have transferred all the rights of my child to the mother so I don't hold any legal parental rights .. So I don't have any connection in that sense .. What do I need o do in terms of being emphatic

Comment: @dumbcoder ... As I Have not overstated  after my asylum ... Do you think it will still be showing up / or recorded? On my electronic record

Comment: Sorry, Mathur, your question is very unclear. Please [edit] it, mention all the facts in chronological order, add the info that you wrote in comments into it, end with the *specific* question(s) you want answered.

Answer (score 3):

It will be on your electronic record. Ireland and the UK share Immigration related information due to the Common Travel Area. A new passport does not wipe your prior history.

Edit:

Furthermore, if you look at the [Study Visa Questionnaire](https://www.dfa.ie/media/embassyindia/ourservices/Student_Questionnaire_May-2016.pdf) for India, they ask about your travel history. I quote from the form:

> Have you ever applied for a visa for any other country?
>
> If yes, please give full details in the box below including; country, date of application, type of visa applied for and outcome of application: Refusal letter must be submitted.
>
> NOTE: Failure to declare ALL previous visa applications will result in the application being
> refused

Comment: it does however flag that the inspector should pay extra attention

Comment: So what's the probability that I will be accepted for any Student visa anywhere. As I am aswell thinking for applying to Ireland .

Comment: @Mathur we don't issue probabilities here. You are more than free to apply, but your immigration record is probably in the Schengen Information System. From the top comments above, I can see you were placed in detention. This does not help your case. I would find it very hard to believe that you are an actual student. If I worked for the GNIB, I would see you as wanting to use Ireland as a backdoor for the UK.

Comment: But I don't have any criminal records of any sort. I could provide the documents for that . Do you think still I would be refused ?! Could I not travel anywhere else ever in future becoz of this ?! I m worried now . Of the stupid mistake I took .. The reason for me to apply asylum is to be there at the time of birth of my child ... It was a bad legal advice given to me .. But it's in the past now .. As I realised it was a bad idea I decided to apply voluntary return . But uk isn't a part of schengan is it ?!

Comment: You are a not a citizen of Ireland or UK nor an EEU member. You are therefore not entitled to the right to enter the Republic of Ireland, with or without a criminal record. You need to convince the immigration authorities that you are a bona fide student. I doubt you will able to show that.

Comment: UK is not part of Schengen but they do share information with each other to combat this type of activity.

Comment: It's appalling to know that terrorists could manage to get away from these things and someone who was working in the community and supporting charities and a proper tax payers until the moment I left job as I had applied for asylum .. A law abiding citizen as long as I was there ... I am ready to say the truth but would they see through it and accept or will I be refused ?! Could I not travel to anywhere like

Comment: @Mathur you got a good answer to your question and that's how the site works. Comments are for clarifications to the original question and not to introduce new material or to debate the merits of your case.  You can benefit from reading the help page at https://travel.stackexchange.com/help  Please use the 'accept' button for this answer, many thanks.

Comment: Thank you Gayot Fow ... I have one last doubt to be clarified ... @Rodney Hawkins when you say i have it in as electronic record ... You mean to say my travel history to uk or does it include my application of asylum aswell in there ?!

Comment: @Mathur You can ask for a Freedom of Information request to see what the UK holds on your file, but what is transmitted between the countries is confidential and I am not privy to that data. See my edit above regarding the questionnaire.

Comment: @ Rodney Hawkins aye I am aware of it. Do I have to inform my asylum application in there? I don't have the refusal letter in hand atm though ! Becoz I didn't plan to study research now . What if I happen to mention I don't have the refusal letter hard copy probably I have brief refusal reason on my immigration history sheet . Is that ok ? Or can they access my refusal sheet of the U.K. Immigration?

Comment: Rodney Hawkins ... Could you please send us the link where to request for information From the uk . Am I going to answer this question every single place I m going to ? Or is it just Ireland ? Does the EU ask the same ?